# How to combine array values in PHP loop based on the same key

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create array within foreach loop, where would be patients count by medicine for specific physician, but I am only getting one number in the array which is wrong, since I am generating a chart with the response and I need all the patients count in one array. Also if there is no data for that physician for that medicine, then it needs to be 0.

This is the current response from the server.

```
array:5 
  0 => array:4 
    "patientsCount" => 2
    "brand_name" => "Medicine 1"
    "month" => "April"
    "physician_name" => "John Doe"
  ]
  1 => array:4 
    "patientsCount" => 1
    "brand_name" => "Medicine 2"
    "month" => "April"
    "physician_name" => "Jane Doe"
  ]
  2 => array:4 
    "patientsCount" => 5
    "brand_name" => "Medicine 3"
    "month" => "July"
    "physician_name" => "John Doe"
  ]
  3 => array:4 
    "patientsCount" => 5
    "brand_name" => "Medicine 2"
    "month" => "July"
    "physician_name" => "Jane Doe"
  ]
  4 => array:4 
    "patientsCount" => 2
    "brand_name" => "Medicine 4"
    "month" => "June"
    "physician_name" => "John Doe"
  ]
]
```

In my foreach loop I am doing this

```
$arr[ $item['physician_name'] ] = [ $item['patientsCount'] ];
```

Which gives me this

```
    array:2 
      "John Doe" => array:1 
        0 => 2
      ]
      "Jane Doe" => array:1 
        0 => 5
      ]
    ]
```

My expected result would be this

```
  0 => array:5 
        "label" => "John Doe"
        "data" => array:5 
          0 => 3
          1 => 0
          2 => 8
          3 => 7
          4 => 4
        ]
        "borderWidth" => 1
        "backgroundColor" => "rgba(226,46,111,0.2)"
        "borderColor" => "rgba(226,46,111,1)"
      ]
      1 => array:5 
        "label" => "Jane Doe"
        "data" => array:5
          0 => 6
          1 => 7
          2 => 0
          3 => 11
          4 => 4
        ]
        "borderWidth" => 1
        "backgroundColor" => "rgba(226,46,111,0.2)"
        "borderColor" => "rgba(226,46,111,1)"
      ]
    ]
```

How can I get the expected array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In...

```
$arr[ $item['physician_name'] ] = [ $item['patientsCount'] ];
```

You will continually overwrite the same element of the array with an array containing `$item['patientsCount']`.  What you want is to add to this array...

```
 $arr[ $item['physician_name'] ][] = $item['patientsCount'];
```

Note the `[]` on the left hand side of the `=`, which means add the value to the end of this array.